# How to accept XML post request in php?

Tags: php, xml, request

For an android application, data needs to be posted as a xml request to a php file. 
How can the XML request be read at the php end.

Answer (score 2):

Use [php://input](http://php.net/wrappers.php) and [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to fetch the raw input.

```
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
```